# Full page reload with HTML 5 popState when Back button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, pushstate

As long as I navigate inside my app then `history.pushState` and `window.onpopstate` work perfectly. Page content is updated, AJAX requests are fetched/re-fetched.

The problem is when I navigate away to a completely different page (outside my mini single page app).

When I press the **Back** button, it takes me to the *contents of AJAX request (without CSS, header, footer)*, instead of *fully loaded page + contents of AJAX request*.

This behavior works just fine when I navigate forward and backward within this single page app, i.e. when I press the Back button, I only want the contents of the AJAX request, not the entire page.

Is there any way to force it to load the full page instead of going back to the AJAX request when it detects user has navigated away from the single page app?

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the url you set in pushstate gets a full page when called other than by ajax.

Comment: I want to add that it only happens on Chrome with Dev Tools closed, not on Firefox or Safari.